# Connect and reconnect automatically to the VPN

Tags: vpn

Could you please answer me about how I can turn my VPN connection on automatically after logon? And if connection is lost what I can do to auto reconnect it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the VPN autoconnect by first setting up a vpn connection under the network settings. Then go to the ethernet or wifi tab and click on settings. Then under the general tab you can set it to autoconnect to the selected vpn for that connection.

Comment: Yep thanks, I just saw into my network connection this options, autoconnect to the vpn then use this lan/wan connection. Okay, thanks. I think this is resolved question. Thanks.